# ajax rating control with facebook login

Tags: asp.net, ajax, facebook-graph-api, facebook-c#-sdk

I have a video website. I want the users to vote for the videos with their facebook ids. What i want is to put an ajax rating control under videos. If the user is currently logged in on facebook, when the user clicks the control to rate the video i want to get the user id of the facebook user. If the user is not logged in I want to show a modal popup for facebook login and get the user id after user is logged in.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am not wrong you will have to go all the way and create an App in Facebook and integrate it with your site. 
You may first want to check the Javascript SDK 
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/

If that doesn't work, I have a blog article that does the full server side integration
http://theocdcoder.com/tutorial-integrating-facebook-authentication-asp-net-mvc-3/